# Vapor 3 - URLSession or AJAX?

Tags: swift, web, vapor

I am new with Vapor and I am confused about how to make a url request in Vapor Web.

I'd like to use the Vapor web API from cryptocompare.com. Is the best solution to use Swift URLSession or to use JavaScript in the web page?

Comment: See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a question.

Comment: Are you looking for [Client](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/vapor/content/#client)?

Comment: To exand on a previoius comment … note that the [Vapor 'Client' API](https://api.vapor.codes/vapor/latest/Vapor/Protocols/Client.html) can connect to remote HTTP servers, send HTTP requests, and receive HTTP responses. For example, experiment with `let result = try req.client().get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR")` and look at the reponse with `print(res) // Future<Response>`.